# How do I fix could not convert string to float: ''? (Updated)

Tags: python

I created a program that keeps popping up with an error message that says

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/salvas/Downloads/Salvas6/program6_2.py", line 23, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/salvas/Downloads/Salvas6/program6_2.py", line 12, in main
    reg_price = float(prices_file.readline())
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

The program is supposed to use information from a file and display it in a table. I was able to get it to print the information correctly, however, now it comes up with this error. The data includes a destination, the regular price of traveling to this destination, and the discounted percentage which gets calculated into a discounted price in this program. This is the data that I imported from a .txt file that was created using a different program:

```
San Francisco\n
550\n
10\n
New Orleans\n
330\n
10\n
Atlanta\n
295\n
20
```

```
def main():
    prices_file = open('prices.txt', 'r')
    destination = prices_file.readline()
    column1 = 'DESTINATION'
    column2 = 'REG.PRICE'
    column3 = 'REDUCED'
    column4 = 'SALE PRICE'
    print(f'{column1:<}\t{column2:}\t{column3:}\t\t{column4:}')
    while destination != '':
        reg_price = float(prices_file.readline())
        reduc_percent = float(prices_file.readline())
        percentage = reduc_percent / 100
        reduced = percentage * reg_price
        sale_price = reg_price - reduced
        destination = destination.rstrip('\n')
        print(f'{destination:<}\t${reg_price:.2f}\t\t${reduced:.2f}\t\t${sale_price:.2f}')
        destination = prices_file.readline()
    prices_file.close()
       
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This is the program that I created that keeps coming up with an error message.

(I made a few changes based on the suggestions I was given, however, I am now given a new error message that I explained above.)

Comment: fyi `prices_file.close` doesn't do anything. You're just accessing the `close` attribute, but you're not actually calling `()` the method. In any case, you might want to consider using a context manager instead: `with open(...):`

Comment: _"keeps coming up with an error message"_ Please [edit] your question to include the full error message, including the exception traceback.

Comment: Showing your input is _part_ of building a [mre], but we also expect both actual and expected output.

Comment: (It would also be appreciated if you could write a title that narrowly describes your specific technical problem; _lots_ of people have questions about how to process "certain lines in certain ways" when the lines they want and the ways they want to process them don't match yours, so the question isn't actually identifying your specific problem in enough detail to let someone else find it and learn from its answers).

Answer (score 0):

You are reading the price and percent lines each time around the loop, but only read the destination at the start before the loop, and then again at the end.

Correct the indentation of the `destination = prices_file.readline()` line so it is part of the loop.

Comment: This worked! However, now the error message says could not convert string to float: ''

Comment: @confused read each line into a separate variable, check whether it is empty (like you do for `destination`) and stop looping if it is as you have reached the end of the file

Comment: Im not sure I understand completely